# form value fill using javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-manipulation, getelementsbyname

i am filling this value using javascript code. after that i am able to see this value in cosole. but value not visible in box. due to this i am unable to click submit button.this element is in a form tag.images link
https://i.stack.imgur.com/quZ8f.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9KgX.jpg

```
function myfn(){
  document.getElementsByName("ELEC_CURR_B_PHASE").value="415V";
  var x= document.getElementsByName("ELEC_CURR_B_PHASE").value="415V";
  console.log(x);

};myfn()
```

[result after running code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quZ8f.png)
[inspect element image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9KgX.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByName()` returns a NodeList and to set the property value, select the first index.

```
function myfn(){
  document.getElementsByName("ELEC_CURR_B_PHASE").value="415V";
  var x= document.getElementsByName("ELEC_CURR_B_PHASE")[0].value="415V";
  console.log(x);
};
myfn();
```

Comment: Great! please mark this as the answer so it may help others as well.